# Crontab -e simple problem

Tags: command-line, cron, raspberry-pi

I was newbbbie of crontab command, and while i was investigating this command, i suddenly type some number and made my crontab -e look like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ crontab -e
no crontab for pi - using an empty one
889
```

is there any way to set crontab back to default or how to delete them? i just want use crontab to automatic doing my tasks.

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').
#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
"/tmp/crontab.QzVh1G/crontab" 23 lines, 898964 characters
```

it show like this after I follow your instruction `export VISUAL=vi crontab -e`and it seems i can not edit this file except using qa! to exit. is there anything i missed?

Comment: I see you've got an answer to this, but also know that you can *list* your `crontab` with `crontab -l` - no edits are possible, only a listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your editor is set to `ed`.  The `ed` editor is a *very basic* line editor which will output the number of bytes in the file when you open it.  In this case, you crontab file contains 889 bytes (type `,p` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the editor to see the contents of the file).

You most likely don't want to use `ed` as you editor (or you would have recognized that you had started it).  To exit the editor, simply type `q` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>.

Then run `crontab -e` again, but with the `VISUAL` environment variable set to the editor that you most commonly use to edit files on your system.

Here is how you may set `VISUAL` to `vi`, as an example, but you may use `nano` or any other terminal editor that happens to be installed.

```
export VISUAL=vi
crontab -e
```

You may want to set the value of `VISUAL` in your shell's startup file (in `~/.bashrc` if you're using `bash`).

Comment: thanks, by the way how do i edit this file? it seems to me i can only type qa！to quit

Comment: @Norman I don't know what you're doing (as I can't see it), but I'm assuming you've started the Vim editor to edit your crontab file. If you're unfamiliar with that editor too, then use the `nano` editor or some other editor that you're more used to using on your system.

Comment: i will show you  it wait a s.

Comment: @Norman Yes, so that has opened the file in Vim. If you're unfamiliar with how to use the Vim editor, I would suggest using whatever other editor you are familiar with on your system.  The `nano` editor is usually used as a "easy to use editor". You would have to make sure that `nano` is installed and then set `VISUAL` to `nano`.

Comment: thanks very much